# Conditional rule always trigger job

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

Version used: gitlab.com (free tier)

I have this rule on a job

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"'
      when: never
```

The way I understand it (which is also what I want it to do), is that it should prevent the job from being added to the pipeline when the contents of variable `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` equals `trigger`.

This is not the case, and the job in question is always removed from the pipeline.

The pipeline is triggered by an API call from another pipeline
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/

What am I doing wrong ?

**Edit**

The variable value is displayed on the pipeline screen

[image: variable value]

Comment: You havent mentioned how you actually trigger your pipeline. Please share other parts of your gitlab-ci.yml to understand how other jobs in the same pipeline are triggered.

Comment: It is triggered via an api call https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/

Comment: Can you create another job in the pipeline (that always runs) to echo the contents of `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` to confirm the value is what you expect? Are you using any other rules?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the rule's value. It is the only rule I am using on the pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct behaviour as per documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules):
[image]

As in this example [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html) you probably need to include the `when: on_success`

```
job:
  script: echo "Hello, Rules!"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - when: on_success
```

Comment: It worked but also generated a duplicate pipeline so I had to combine the `rules` tag with a `workflow` tag that specifies when a pipeline should run